# preserveAspectRatio of pattern image in SVG like css background-image cover

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, svg

I have an SVG that is two triangles placed diagonally to make a rectangle. This rectangle is 100% width and height of the browser window. I am trying to fill each with one background image. To do this, I put the image into a pattern and gave each triangle a fill with that pattern.
However, the image in the pattern does not maintain it's ratio on window resize. The image stretches and distorts. I want the image to act similar to how this css would work:

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

This is the code I have so far for the svg:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 25 25" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="pattern3" height="100%" width="100%"
         patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" viewBox="0 0 1 1"
         preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
            <image height="1" width="1"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" 
              xlink:href="img/1.JPG" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <polyline points="0,0  25,0  0,25"
        fill="url(#pattern3)" id="top"/>
    <polyline points="25,0  25,25  0,25"
        fill="url(#pattern3)"  id="bottom"/>
</svg>
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 4):

You can fix this by changing the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute in your root SVG to something else.  For example:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 25 25" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
     width="100%" height="100%">
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3uR9R/)

Comment: Is there anyway to perform this without changing the aspect ratio of the root SVG? I don't want the triangles to be sliced from the top and the bottom, I want them to fully span the screen.

Comment: Having `preserveAspectRatio="none"` in the root svg element will always cause the contents to be stretched or squeezed. There is no way for the inner contents to override that.  The only solution would be to use Javascript to set the size of the triangles.

Comment: The image gets stretched (albeit proportionately) a lot on window resize with your code. I want it to act more like background-cover which is much more intuitive and doesn't stretch the background image to a ridiculously large size when the window gets larger, but rather moves the image around to cover the area. How would I go about doing that?